Executing DAG pipeline with ansible
I have 3 ansible tasks (A, B, C). I want task A and B to be run concurrently and C to be executed as soon as A and B are finished (C uses data from A's and B's stdout). So, if each task takes 30 seconds to finish, I expect the entire pipeline to be executed in 60 seconds (30 seconds for concurrent A and B and 30 seconds for C).
tasks:
  - name: A
    shell:
      cmd: "sleep 30"
    async: 1000
    poll: 0
  - name: B
    shell:
      cmd: "sleep 30"
    async: 1000
    poll: 0
  - name: C
    shell:
      cmd: "sleep 30"
    # what to add here?

I tried to use async_status + until (in C) but I can't mix it with an actual shell module.

This looks like what you are trying to acheive. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28997#issuecomment-1197261716

Q: "I expect the entire pipeline to be executed in 60 seconds (30 seconds for concurrent A and B and 30 seconds for C)"
This is not going to happen because of overhead (protocols, communication, network, processing, etc. ...).
Q: "I want task A and B to be run concurrently and C to be executed as soon as A and B are finished, whereby C uses data from A's and B's stdout."
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - block:

      - name: A
        shell:
          cmd: "echo 'TASK A'; sleep 30"
        register: A
        async: 60
        poll: 0

      - name: B
        shell:
          cmd: "echo 'TASK B'; sleep 30"
        register: B
        async: 60
        poll: 0

    - name: Wait until Concurrent Remote Tasks are complete
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ item }}"
      # Inner loop
      loop:
        - "{{ A.ansible_job_id }}"
        - "{{ B.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: async_status
      # Outer loop
      until: async_status is finished
      delay: 30
      retries: 1

      # Since C uses data from A's and B's 'stdout'
      # need to 'slurp' the Async Remote Results before

    - name: Gathering Async Remote Results
      slurp:
        src: "/home/ansible_user/.ansible_async/{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "{{ A.ansible_job_id }}"
        - "{{ B.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: async_tasks

    - name: C
      shell:
        cmd: "echo 'Output from {{ _A }} and {{ _B }}'; sleep 30"
      register: C
      # Because the 'content' of Remote Results file is a Base64 encoded JSON string
      vars:
        _A: "{{ ((async_tasks.results[0].content | b64decode) | from_json).stdout }}"
        _B: "{{ ((async_tasks.results[1].content | b64decode) | from_json).stdout }}"

    - name: Final result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ C.stdout }}"

will result into the expected behavior and an output of
PLAY [test] ********************************************************************************************
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:19:24 +0200 (0:00:00.015)       0:00:00.015 ******

TASK [A] ***********************************************************************************************
changed: [test.example.com]
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:19:26 +0200 (0:00:02.451)       0:00:02.467 ******

TASK [B] ***********************************************************************************************
changed: [test.example.com]
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:19:27 +0200 (0:00:00.721)       0:00:03.188 ******
FAILED - RETRYING: [test.example.com]: Wait until Concurrent Remote Tasks are complete (1 retries left).

TASK [Wait until Concurrent Remote Tasks are complete] *************************************************
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=j989601333376.1621265)
changed: [test.example.com] => (item=j524870789757.1621464)
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:19:59 +0200 (0:00:32.200)       0:00:35.389 ******

TASK [Gathering Async Remote Results] ******************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] => (item=j989601333376.1621265)
ok: [test.example.com] => (item=j524870789757.1621464)
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:20:01 +0200 (0:00:01.423)       0:00:36.813 ******

TASK [C] ***********************************************************************************************
changed: [test.example.com]
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:20:31 +0200 (0:00:30.666)       0:01:07.480 ******

TASK [Final result] ************************************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: Output from TASK A and TASK B

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
test.example.com : ok=6    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 1 minutes, 7 seconds
Wednesday 21 August 2024  09:20:31 +0200 (0:00:00.033)       0:01:07.513 ******
===============================================================================
Wait until Concurrent Remote Tasks are complete ------------------------------------------------- 32.20s
C ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 30.67s
A ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 2.45s
Gathering Async Remote Results ------------------------------------------------------------------- 1.42s
B ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.72s
Final result ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.03s

real    1m14.259s
user    0m3.187s
sys     0m1.210s

Since this Use Case is somehow related to Distributed Computing one need to know what should run when, where and with which information. In example, if C should also run on all Remote Nodes it is probably not necessary to transfer the asynchronous task results over to the Control Node and the necessary facts together with the next task back to the Remote Node. Means, maybe slurp could become dropped and the parameter vars changed.
For reference and to show how the Async Remote Results look like on the Remote Node test.example.com:
ansible_user@test:~$ ll .ansible_async/*1621*
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 455 Aug 21 09:19 .ansible_async/j524870789757.1621464
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 455 Aug 21 09:19 .ansible_async/j989601333376.1621265
ansible_user@test:~$ cat .ansible_async/j989601333376.1621265
{"changed": true, "stdout": "TASK A", "stderr": "", "rc": 0, "cmd": "echo 'TASK A'; sleep 30", "start": "2024-08-21 09:19:27.054680", "end": "2024-08-21 09:19:57.059728", "delta": "0:00:30.005048", "msg": "", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "echo 'TASK A'; sleep 30", "_uses_shell": true, "stdin_add_newline": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "argv": null, "chdir": null, "executable": null, "creates": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null}}}
ansible_user@test:~$ cat .ansible_async/j524870789757.1621464
{"changed": true, "stdout": "TASK B", "stderr": "", "rc": 0, "cmd": "echo 'TASK B'; sleep 30", "start": "2024-08-21 09:19:27.779355", "end": "2024-08-21 09:19:57.784012", "delta": "0:00:30.004657", "msg": "", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "echo 'TASK B'; sleep 30", "_uses_shell": true, "stdin_add_newline": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "argv": null, "chdir": null, "executable": null, "creates": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null}}}

